# dynamic type casting throws unusual exception for identical eventhandler signatures?

Tags: vb.net, casting, delegates

---

```
Imports System
Imports System.Reflection
Imports System.Reflection.Emit
```

---

```
'Static type casting ..... Success!
Dim a = CType(Sub(sender As Control, e As ColumnWidthChangedEventArgs)
                   foo()
              End Sub, System.Windows.Forms.ColumnWidthChangedEventHandler)
'Extracting windows.forms assembly namespace .....
Dim assemblyname As String = ""
For Each assem As Assembly In AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()
   If (assem.GetName().Name = "System.Windows.Forms") Then
         assemblyname = assem.FullName
         Exit For
   End If
Next
'Dynamic type casting ..... Fail!
a = CTypeDynamic(Sub(sender As object, e As ColumnWidthChangedEventArgs)
                    foo()
                 End Sub,
                 Assembly.Load(assemblyname).GetType("System.Windows.Forms.ColumnWidthChangedEventHandler"))
```

the second assignment fails with `System.InvalidCastException`, I tried :

```
a = CTypeDynamic(New listview,
                 Assembly.Load(assemblyname).GetType("System.Windows.Forms.ListView"))
```

All looks fine, types are homologuous and the assembly file is compatible, where is the mismatch or the misuse here ?

### Error details:

*Assembly name*:

> Microsoft.VisualBasic.CompilerServices.Conversions
>
> Microsoft.VisualBasic, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a

*Error context:*

> Conversion from type 'VB$AnonymousDelegate_4(Of Object,ColumnWidthChangedEventArgs)' to type 'ColumnWidthChangedEventHandler' is not valid

Comment: If you use a Lambda that actually matches the signature of the `ColumnWidthChangedEventHandler` delegate, does it work then?

Comment: @jmcilhinney yes i used it in the very first attempt with direct casting, whether it fails with dynamic casting, assembly instance is sane look at the later example, it returned a proper format for the listview.

Comment: I think signatures are identical, the nuance in function declaration `Function->Sub` doesn't have any effect

Comment: "i used it in the very first attempt with direct casting".  No, you didn't.  The `ColumnWidthChangedEventHandler` delegate is a `Sub` and has a `sender` parameter of type `Object`. I ask again, does it work if you use a Lambda with `CTypeDynamic` if you use the proper signature?

Comment: By the way, the code you posted wouldn't even compile, so you clearly haven't posted the actual code you're using.

Comment: @jmcilhinney of course it does !!!!! you just have to entitle it with some headers and define a custom foo function

Comment: Of course what does what? Maybe you could be clear about what you mean. Are you saying, without actually saying, that the code you posted does compile? If so then, I would beg to differ. I haven't specifically tested but I would be surprised if a Lambda that started with `function` and ended with `End Sub` would compile.

Comment: oh that was a blunder, corrected

Answer (score 1):

Initially I was thinking it was a difference in the way CTypeDynamic works under the hood and the fact that your signature doesn't match.

But it is looking like a bug in the .Net Framework and it has nothing to due with the type being known at compile time.

I changed your signature:

```
Function(sender As Control, e As ColumnWidthChangedEventArgs)
```

to the correct one:

```
Sub(sender As object, e As ColumnWidthChangedEventArgs)
```

But you same error occurs even if you use the correct signature in a Generic method using CType. Further more, you can't even use TryCast.

```
Public Function ConvertGenericType(Of T)(obj As Object) As T
    Return CType(obj, T)
End Function

Public Sub RunTest()

    ''public delegate void ColumnWidthChangedEventHandler(object sender, ColumnWidthChangedEventArgs e)

    Dim MyDelegate = Sub(sender As Object, e As ColumnWidthChangedEventArgs)
                         Console.WriteLine("FOO")
                     End Sub
    'Works
    Dim CastOne = CType(MyDelegate, ColumnWidthChangedEventHandler)

    'Works
    Dim CastTwo As ColumnWidthChangedEventHandler = MyDelegate

    'Works
    Dim CastThree As ColumnWidthChangedEventHandler = Sub(sender As Object, e As ColumnWidthChangedEventArgs)
                                                          Console.WriteLine("FOO")
                                                      End Sub

    ' Blows Up
    Dim CastFour = ConvertGenericType(Of ColumnWidthChangedEventHandler)(MyDelegate)
    ' Exception: System.InvalidCastException: 'Unable to cast object of type VB$AnonymousDelegate_0`2[System.Object,System.Windows.Forms.ColumnWidthChangedEventArgs]'
    '    to type 'System.Windows.Forms.ColumnWidthChangedEventHandler'.'

    ' Won't Compile: ColumnWidthChangedEventHandler
    'TryCast(MyDelegate, ColumnWidthChangedEventHandler)
    'Sub <generated method>(sender As Object, e As ColumnWidthChangedEventArgs) can't be converted to  o type 'System.Windows.Forms.ColumnWidthChangedEventHandler'
End Sub
```